Bluetooth devices are not getting connected anymore
I accidently run the command:
sudo apt uninstall bluez

After running it, the devices are not getting connected anymore. I can click on the connection button, but it doesn't work
I keep clicking on the connection button, but it doesn't connect to the device
What should i do?

Did you try installing BlueZ using the command sudo apt install bluez??

bluez is the bluetooth package that allows bluetooth to work

Yes, i  have run the command 'sudo apt install bluez', but still bluetooth is not working
